# How to "ping" people who voted to close a question so they review their vote?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, vote-to-close

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/208378/root-access-on-my-own-server/208402#comment260194_208402) was closed as off-topic - I believe it is not, maybe it was worded too vaguely or mentioned too many irrelevant details or something.

Now, I edited the question to make it more direct and voted to re-open it. However, from my experience, once closed a question gets very little attention so there's not many chances to get another 4 votes necessary to re-open it.

What is the correct procedure to notify the people who voted to close the question so they can review their vote?

Comment: Yes, you are correct-it was a mistake. I've just voted to reopen it- it now has 4 reopen votes, so it should be reopened soon.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of nagging to the users that closed a question a smarter way to do this is to just flag your post for moderation review and let a moderator handle your case. Takes away all the bureaucratic view and the discussion out of the equation.

Once a moderator re-opens your question there will be no way that the same users that voted to close it on the first place to do it again.

Answer (score 2):

There really is no way. However, you can ask in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) and there should be enough 3K users to look at your post and discuss it. Also, if you cast a reopen vote, and a comment or edit entailing this, it will arrive in the [Reopen Vote Queue](https://askubuntu.com/review/reopen) where it will be looked upon by quite a few users. If a closevoter also left a comment, you can notify them with the @User ping, of course.

With that said, can you provide a link so I can possibly try to reopen?

Comment: Here's the link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/208378/root-access-with-scp

You're in the list of voters, btw :)

Comment: @Sergey My apologies. I'll see whether I should cast a reopen vote. Edit: IMO it shouldn't have been closed. I've voted to reopen, and sorry for the overlook on my part.